# How to upload images in feathersjs and store it directly in mongodb database using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, file-upload, feathersjs

I am working on a project where I want to store the profile image of an user in the database.
Actually what I want to is to store the image itself in database not its URL or address and also I should be able to get the images from database. I am using feathersjs and mongoose

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing that but base on your question, you did not start anything yet. How about you try this one.

https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-blob

Comment: okay thanks will look into it. So using this  method we can actually store the image as binary data in the database?

Comment: yeah, but there might be some restrictions, please check https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/